# Normal approximation to Poisson's distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, poisson-distribution

> Historic data of a computer network suggest that connections with this network follow a Poisson's distribution with an average of 5 connections per minute. Find $t_0$, which has probability equal to $0.9$ to happen at least once before $t_0$

I made an approximation using $\lambda=12$, since $5/60 =1/12$, but my answer doesn't match with the book (book says it's ~$27.5$ seconds, and mine ~$17.0$ seconds)

Could someone help me?

Comment: @Henry typo, corrected.

Comment: There is little or no practical need for approximations for this problem in today's age of computers. I suggest you dispense with the complication of deriving an approximation, and simply calculate the probability exactly (or to the desired digits of precision).

Answer (score 1):

Let $(X_t)_{t \in [0,\infty)}$ be a Poisson process where $t$ is minutes.
$$\begin{aligned}P(X_{t_0}\geq 1)&=0.9\\
1-P(X_{t_0}=0)&=0.9\\
1-\frac{e^{-\lambda t_0}(\lambda t_0)^0}{0!}&=0.9\\
e^{-\lambda t_0}&=0.1\\
t_0&=-\ln(0.1)/\lambda
\end{aligned}$$
If we express $t_0$ in seconds we get $t_0\cdot 60\approx 27.63$ where $\lambda =5$.

Comment: I didn't know of Poisson process, seems my book talks about it at the exponential distribution's chapter. I'm going to reread it, thanks.